# Need to get multiplier that will bring fractions of a cent to a whole cent

Tags: php, math, decimal

I want to be able to specify a fraction of a cent (100th max) in a php application.  I need to figure out how many iterations it would take to reach an even whole cent.  I inherited an application that was supposedly doing this, but it's not working at all. Is there any direction someone can point me in? I apologize if this is beyond simple.  I am just blanking out.  In our app, it was doing something like this:

```
$integerPayout  = (int)floor($payout * 10000);
$count     = 1;
$modAmount = 100; 
while(($integerPayout * $count) % $modAmount != 0)
$count += 1;
echo $count;
```

Comment: Let me be the first to tell you that you shouldn't handle actual money with floating-point numbers.

Comment: what is $co in the while loop?

Answer (score 1):

[`lcm`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.math.php#13343)`(100, (int)($payout * 100)) / (int)($payout * 100)`